# PHP code after greater than (>) shows in HTML

Tags: php

I'm using nginx with php5-fpm on a Xubuntu ARM box (Odroid U3). The following code prints part of the PHP script to HTML. The code itself is located in a function of a file that is being included:

```
<div class="date right clear">
        <? echo ((strtotime($order[0]['created']) > 0) && isset($order[0]['created'])) ? date("d.m.Y", strtotime($order[0]['created'])) : date("d.m.Y", time()); ?>
</div>
```

The output is:

```
0) && isset($order[0]['created'])) ? date("d.m.Y", strtotime($order[0]['created'])) : date("d.m.Y", time()); ?>
```

I think the script is fine because it works on a different machine (Xubuntu machine with Intel architecture). Is this a bug or are my PHP settings messed up?

Comment: short tags is the culprit <?... change them to <?php

Comment: If you want a quick fix run this on cmd line: `sudo echo "short_open_tag = On" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` restart apache... sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to different php configuration on the servers. This you are using right now doesn't accept `short tags <?`. Either change your php.ini to allow them or use long ones `<?php`

From [**documentation**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

> PHP also allows for short open tags  (which are discouraged because they are only available if enabled with short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option.

Comment: You are right. For some reason I missed that the short tags were used here and are deprecated. Replacing them with <?php works.